# Can I force Django to load images with space in the filename?

Tags: django, image, whitespace

I have a folder with image files. Unfortunately, some files contain a space in their name. Django is able to load these images if I run the app on the development server (via `python manage.py runserver`) but not if I run it in production. The reason is that Django converts `" "` to `"%20"`.

For example, if my folder contains the following files:

- image1.png
- image2 test.png
- image3%20test.png *(just to understand what is happening)*

... then this code will have the following result:

```
# In settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = ('D:/Data/Images')

# In the HTML template
<img src="/media/image1.png"/> # image loads on the development and production server
<img src="/media/image2 test.png"/> # image loads only on the development server
<img src="/media/image3 test.png"/> # image loads only on the production server
```

I could of course rename all image filenames that contain space characters by replacing the spaces with underscores. But that's a bit awkward as a chemical analysis system is constantly feeding new image files to the folder and the system's software will occasionally introduce spaces in the filenames. I do not have control over this.
So is there a way to force Django to load images even if they contain space characters?

Comment: Please *don't*. Spaces in filenames are a *horrible* idea, no really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Good Practice But, you can do using custom **`FileSystemStorage`**

#### custom_storage.py

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class CustomStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        return name  # No modification to the name
```

#### models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from .custom_storage import CustomStorage  # Import the CustomStorage class

class YourModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', storage=CustomStorage())
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the option to create a CustomStorage class. As a Django newbie, I wasn't aware that this is possible. However, after having a close look at it, I decided to follow willeM_ Van Onsem's recommendation to avoid file names with spaces. I solved it with a script that renames the files created by the upstream system. That was the easier solution in my case. But CustomStorage looks like a great feature for my future apps.